# Area of ellipse given foci?

Tags: conic-sections

Is it possible to get the area of an ellipse from the foci alone? Or do I need at least one point on the ellipse too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sum of the distance to the foci is just the distance between the foci, the ellipse shrinks to a line. If it is bigger, then the area is strictly positive.

This tells you that the foci alone are not sufficient to know the area. A point on the ellipse will be sufficient, but of course other information will also be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If the foci are points $p,q\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ on a horizontal line
and a point on the ellipse is $c\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then the string
length $\ell=\left|p-c\right|+\left|q-c\right|$ (the distance from
the first focus to the point on the ellipse to the second focus) determines
the semi-axis lengths. Using the Pythagorean theorem, the vertical
semi-axis has length $\sqrt{\frac{\ell^{2}}{4}-\frac{\left|p-q\right|^{2}}{4}}$.
Using the fact that the horizontal semi-axis is along the line joining
$p$ to $q$, the horizontal semi-axis has length $\frac{\ell}{2}$.
Thus the area is $\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell^{2}-\left|p-q\right|^{2}}{4}}\frac{\ell}{2}$
($\pi$ times each semi-major axis length, analogous to the circle
area formula $\pi r^{2}$).